# NodeJS and console.log not logging

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, its been a hot minute since I've used node, and i can not for the life of me, understand why this isn't working.

```
const body_parser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname +  "/Contents/"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    //Why wont this log to my terminal when a user visits the site?
    console.log("log it pleaseeeeeeeeee");
});

app.listen(5004, () => {
   console.log("server up and listening on port 5004");
});
```

I'm trying to log "Log it Pleaseeeee" every time a user visits the site, into the terminal where my nodejs app is running. Why wont this work?

Comment: How are you executing your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 seperate handlers for an endpoint, in your case "/"

To achieve what you want, you must provide a *middleware* function.

`express` will know based on the type of the second argument what to do. *middleware* functions expect 3 arguments; the last being a callback so it knows when you are ready.

You should change your code by moving your *get* function into your `app.use('/', ...)` function and including the callback parameter as follows:

```
const body_parser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use("/", function(req, res, callback) {
   console.log("log it pleaseeeeeeeeee");
   callback()
}, express.static(__dirname +  "/Contents/"));

/** GET RID OF THIS
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   //Why wont this log to my terminal when a user visits the site?
   console.log("log it pleaseeeeeeeeee");
});
*/

app.listen(5004, () => {
   console.log("server up and listening on port 5004");
});
```

Comment: Yup, this solved it. as well as provided a great explanation on how it works. I really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: If you could further explain what the "callback()" is used for in this case that'd be awesome

Comment: Then callback pattern is used throughout NodeJS. When the callback is invoked at the end of your function the next step can be run. This is most useful when your function is doing some I/O work such as making a network request or interacting with the filesystem. In the case of your function it's just what you have to do.